# how to resolve data overriding when getting data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database:

[image]

In Activity A, I click on a class(`listitem`) and then pass the id of that class to this activity like this:-

```
so = getIntent().getStringExtra("send_id");
```

So right now I have the ClassId in this activity inside `so`. Then I run this query:

```
myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ClassStudent");
Query fk=myref.orderByChild("ClassId").equalTo(so);
fk.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        student=dataSnapshot.child("Studentid").getValue().toString();
        //a breakpoint here gives student=oyvEbB0128Y90ADzXnL0UwCUy0Z2                                
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

So in the query I want all the students id that have that classid `orderByChild("ClassId").equalTo(so)`

Then I create a **`FirebaseRecycleradapter`**

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Info,ViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Info,ViewHolder>(Info.class, R.layout.row, ViewHolder.class, fk) {

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, Info model, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(student); //a breakpoint here gives student = 7AnhQ7pRwhXDRqytjSUkoJrOB253
    }
}
```

Now the data is appearing(on phone screen) like this:

**Result**

```
7AnhQ7pRwhXDRqytjSUkoJrOB253
7AnhQ7pRwhXDRqytjSUkoJrOB253
```

The above student id is appearing twice, instead it should be:

**It should be**

```
 7AnhQ7pRwhXDRqytjSUkoJrOB253
 oyvEbB0128Y90ADzXnL0UwCUy0Z2
```

Since both those students are in that class.

I have also overridden, `getItemId` and `getItemViewType`

Comment: Did u try the query without the "equals to" ?

Comment: @TheDude yes I did it retrieved, this `7AnhQ7pRwhXDRqytjSUkoJrOB253` 2 times again, its not getting the other hmm. The problem is between populateviewholder and the query

Comment: may be your "student" variable override the exisiting data.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference classStudentRef = rootRef.child("ClassStudent");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String Studentid = ds.child("Studentid").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", Studentid);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
classStudentRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
7AnhQ7pRwhXDRqytjSUkoJrOB253
oyvEbB0128Y90ADzXnL0UwCUy0Z2
```

**Edit:** To get the name of the student of the coreponding stundet if you need to query your database twice. So, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference classStudentRef = rootRef.child("ClassStudent");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String Studentid = ds.child("Studentid").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", Studentid);

            DatabaseReference studentIdRef = rootRef.child("Student").child(Studentid);
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            studentIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
classStudentRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: it didnt work, in the Log i get that output (I also get that output in the log in the code in my question) but on screen its only this `7AnhQ7pRwhXDRqytjSUkoJrOB253` twice

Comment: Try to use this code inside `((TextView)holder.title.findViewById(android.R.id.textView)).setText(student);` inside `populateViewHolder` method. Does it work now?

Comment: Do you have an error or is printing the same thing again?

Comment: no i actually got null point exception on that, now i added the listener inside populateviewholder, but its still printing the same thing even though in Log im getting the other id

Comment: In this case the problem i think it's in your .XML file. Is there everything alright?

Comment: You said that you are getting NPE above. Why? Should be exactly as yours. You need to instantiate and use that `TextView` inside `populateViewHolder()` method. Find the correct id from your row.xml

Comment: im using the correct id, since its printing on the screen but its printing the same twice instead of printing the other one

Comment: okay i declared a textview inside onDataChange, and i got on the screen this id `7AnhQ7pRwhXDRqytjSUkoJrOB253` and the default text (the one in xml) in the second item.

Comment: There is something else happening there. You are not looping correctly or the TextView is not instantiated correctly for each record.

Comment: is it possible to add two model class in one adapter?

Comment: No, the constructor only allows one model class but you can nest inside a class, another class and use it accordingly.

Comment: not sure if it is possible what I have in mind is like a `join` in sql, it did work in a `listview` but until now not in `recycleradapter`. Because obviously im not gonna post the `id` on the phone screen I need the name which is in another node. So I need to use 2 model classes and they should be in the same adapter then do a query to retrieve name. There is a node `Student` it has `id` and `name`, there is a node `ClassStudent` it has a `Studentid` and `Classid`. Will this work in recycleradapter?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to use nested classes if those classes are related in your tree. In this way you have access to both classes fileds.

Comment: I have updated the database, as you can see the `Studentid` is also under node `Student` for that specific student. So using the relation having that `id` in both node I want to be able to retreive the `name` in a textview and `image` in a imageview` in an adapter. If this works please can you link me somewhere or update your answer. thank you!

Comment: yes querying is not the problem, I know how to do that ( did it in listview) but the problem is doing it in firebaserecycleradapter. Since adapter take one model class and one holder so I think I need another model class and another holder all in one adapter for this to work. The problem is how to write the firebaserecycleradapter (since two model classes with relation and maybe I need more than one holder or it works with only one holder?)

Comment: If you need something different, you can create your own custom adapter, so you can customize it whatever you want.